# Meteor - extract / access Collection document

Tags: node.js, bash, mongodb, meteor, document

I've written a page where users can upload audio files and set them with all kinds of meta data. Next step for me is, on the server end, at certain intervals to check for changes and generate a new package with all the active files.

For the life of me I am unable to access the document.

```
var activeTracks = Tracks.find({"isActive": true});
for(var track in activeTracks)
    console.log( track.val );
```

I get all my active documents, that works fine if I log the activeTracks but how can i access the individual documents?

Reason being that I would ultimately like to access the file url's as I'm using bash to move files to Unity3D to compile assetBundles.

Or can I simply export the results from the query as a JSON file and do the parsing inside Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
activeTracks.forEach(function(track) { 
    console.log( track.val );
});
```

Comment: This is returning undefined in the console.

Comment: Do you have val property? Try to use consol.log( JSON.stringify(track) );

Comment: That seems to do a better job, getting a JSON typed string with a proper structure. Is this the 'correct' way or is there another way to simply access the document properties?

Comment: You can always "simply" access any property. But if it doesn't exist then result will be undefined